# how to write/run specs for files other than model/view/controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Using rails and rspec it's easy to have rspec generate the necessary files for me when I'm using the `rails generate` command with models/views/controllers. But now I want to write specs for a module I wrote. The module is in `/lib/my_module.rb` so I created a spec in `/spec/lib/my_module_spec.rb`

The problem I'm having is that when I try to do `rspec spec/` the file `my_module_spec.rb` is run but the reference to my module in `lib/my_module.rb` can't be found. What's the right way to do this?

Just FYI the `my_module_spec.rb` file does have `require 'spec_helper'` in it already

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "my_module" do
  it "first test"
    result = MyModule.some_method  # fails here because it can't find MyModule
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you include the module in your my_module_spec.rb? Could you provide the source?

Comment: @Jasper I didn't. But I also don't have to when I do it with models/views/controllers.

Comment: do you require the module source file in the related spec?  `require "#{Rails.root}/lib/my_module.rb"` I had a similar issue to what you're seeing and this in conjunction with Jasper's solution below got me where I needed to be.

Comment: @jaydel Interesting, I was hoping there was a less manual way of doing it (similar to models/controllers/views) but I guess that's not the case.

Comment: @Brand maybe you have not included the lib folder in your application.rb? E.g. 'config.autoload_paths << File.join(Rails.root,"lib")'. Maybe rspec is relying on that too, since I have never needed to require modules in specs explicitly so far.

Comment: @Brand my modules are in myappfolder/lib too. My specs look like the one below without the "#{Rails.root}/lib/my_module.rb".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try including the module and maybe wrapping it in an object

```
require 'spec_helper'

#EDIT according to 
# http://stackoverflow.com/users/483040/jaydel
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/my_module.rb"

describe MyModule do

  let(:wrapper){
    class MyModuleWrapper
      include MyModule
    end
    MyModuleWrapper.new
  }

  it "#some_method" do
    wrapper.some_method.should == "something"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your module contain class methods or instance methods?  Remember that only class methods will be available via

```
MyModule.some_method
```

meaning that some_method is defined as

```
def self.some_method
  ...
end
```

If your module contains instance methods, then use Jasper's solution above.  Hope that clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Put the following in your `config/application.rb` file:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{Rails.root}/lib)
```

I was just wrestling with the same problem, and the above worked for me. There's not really any reason you should have to jump through hoops to be able to access your `lib/` files from RSpec and write tests for them.